# Parse - Only one device is Receiving Push Notifications while the others don't...

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, parse-platform

I registered for push notifications and it works fine on my iphone... i receive all push notifications... but when I run the app on an ipad mini... nothing happens. The PN are allowed, but the deviceToken of the Ipads don't appear under the data browser... What can i do? What am i doing wrong? That's my code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"UbrfAs5qZsm1JnIsKVH79OtuOfleWxxV98LTXAHI"
                  clientKey:@"oHEKHzfaV0fkaPGaes2M0H0sQfaWiSnzYCU5lIu1"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

     [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES; }
      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground]; }

     - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; }
```

Comment: What kind of certificate you have uploaded to parse? Development oder Production?